# PostgreSQL: Conditional where clause using regex not working

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to implement conditional where clause that sets `id` when `maybe_numeric` is really numeric, but the following does end up with `ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "xxx"` for non-numeric values.

How can I fix the first condition so that the second condition is evaluated only if the `maybe_numeric` is numeric?

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table st
WHERE NOT ${maybe_numeric} ~ '^\d+$' OR st.id = ${maybe_numeric}::int
```

Comment: Fix your data model. Don't store integers in `text` columns.

Comment: What is `${maybe_numeric}` ? And: I *think* you want `AND`, not `OR`